# Laravel5 populating select error

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

**Controller:**

```
$groups = DB::table('groups')->lists('group_name');
```

**Then Controller->Blade:**

```
return view('dashboard')->with('groups', $groups);
```

**And the Blade:**

```
@if(!empty($groups))
 {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/dashboard/send_group_msg', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
  {!! Form::select('id', $groups, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 {!! Form:close() !!}
@endif
```

But this returns me this error (I tryed every possible way):

```
FatalErrorException in *** line 14:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Line 14 is my last line from document.
As you can see this is basic populating a select form in L5 but doesn't work. I tryed every possible way to do it and I was close only when I put it in array like this:

```
$items = array();

foreach ($groups as $group)
{
    $items[$group->id] = $group->group_name;
}
```

But then this returns me this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Please suggest me a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replacing your

```
{!! Form:close() !!}
```

with

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

you should replace

```
$groups = DB::table('groups')->lists('group_name');
```

with

```
$groups = DB::table('groups')->lists('group_name', 'id');
```

and throw away this

```
$items = array();

foreach ($groups as $group)
{
    $items[$group->id] = $group->group_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
{!! Form:close() !!}
```

is missing a ':'

```
{!! Form::close() !!}
```